# How to get root acess to data/app folder in Android eclipse emulator?

Tags: android

I'm new to Android development. I want to access "data/app folder in Android eclipse emulator to take backup of apk file that store in that directory but unfortunately I am unable to get access to that directory.

I have tried FACTORY_TEST to get root access permission but still no success.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by using adb command : e.g
E:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools>adb pull /data/app/filename.apk e:\

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have root access on the machine it's impossible. The phone need to be rooted in order to allow your app to do this kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

First your phone should be rooted, you can use https://www.kingoapp.com/ for that. 
Next, you should modify the permission of your app access, to do so you have to :

1. Locate your adb.exe folder (you can find it in your sdk folders)
2. Right click
3. open cmd here
4. Type:

   adb shell 
   su 
   chmod 777 /data /data/data /data/data/yourapp

Good luck