# Android eclipse emulator: can't access data/app

Tags: android, android-emulator, root-access

I wanted to delete my custom apps on the Android emulator in Eclipse. I followed [this guide](http://androidcommunity.com/forums/f4/how-to-uninstall-delete-an-application-from-the-emulator-126/) and encountered the same behaviour as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026303/how-to-get-root-acess-to-data-app-folder-in-android-eclipse-emulator). I also tested the root access the same way Arsalan mentioned in his first answer and got the same result.

I would like to try if Vyomas approach works, but I don't know the command for deleting an app.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are getting "rm failed for minesweeper.apk, Read-only file system"

If that's the case, then you could always press "page up" to bring up the menu in the homescreen and uninstalled it through Settings -> applications -> Manage Applications

Or you could keep going comando style and use this from androidkit, worked for me:
Using adb shell :
Important: The device has to be unplugged from USB if you are trying to uninstall from the emulator, else emulator should not be open and device needs to be plugged in the USB of the PC if you are trying to uninstall from the G1 Device. If either of them are not connected the adb shell command will not work.

Go to the shell and making sure adb is in PATH:
Go to shell (from cmd->adb shell or directly through a terminal)

```
#
#cd data
#cd app
#cd ls
#rm com.company.product.apk
```

Comment: Erm, there is no device, I'm using the Eclipse emulator just for testing my apps. Anyway, the Settings' uninstall menu was just the thing I was looking for, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just reset the device on startup if you want it removed? If your using the Eclipse add-on to use the emulator just select the box to wipe user data before you launch?

Si

Comment: Thanks, too, I will keep that in mind if I encounter a similar problem! :)